# Neo4j DBs in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, terminal, graph-databases, ubuntu-16.04

So I'm already familiar with Neo4j on Windows, but recent interests have pushed me to make an ubuntu box to play in. Now, I got everything installed appropriately (to my knowledge) and starting up the neo4j console and browser UI works just fine. That said, in Windows, launching Neo4j first brings up a DB selection window from which you can select the DB you want to play in, create a new DB, or change some configurations. There doesn't seem to be any analogous functionality in the ubuntu terminal that I know of. The neo4j function only takes one of {console | start | stop | restart | status}. Is there a way to select and create different DBs on the fly, or am I forced to contend with workarounds in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows and OSX, neo4j provides installers that install a nice UI for starting/stopping the neo4j server and for more convenient access to the configuration settings.

For linux environments, however, there is no equivalent UI, and you have to start/stop the server from the command line and directly access/edit the config file.

Comment: İndeed. My question isn't asking whether or not there is a Uİ. İt is asking if there are analogous terminal commands for creating and switching BDs. For instance, Uİ Start button corresponds to the "neo4j start" terminal command. İ wondered if there was a command for DB selection as well or if digging into the configurations/filesystem was the only way to switch out of the default DB selection.